# Nuxt Auth Scheme for rotating Refresh Token

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how a custom auth scheme for a system with access and rotating refresh token should look like, can someone help me out here please?

Edit: why use auth in the first place? When I look at the nuxt auth docs for custom schemes, I find it way more complicated than just using localStorage and some middleware.

Comment: I haven't tried much yet, I'm at the planning stage rn. I've worked with nuxt auth before, but that was without (rotating) refresh tokens. And the more I think about it, the less I see any reason why I should use nuxt auth at all. My idea for that would be: access & refresh token in localStorage, user data in vuex for easy access, and /me API endpoint loaded with every initial page load which would get user data and also verify the token automatically. Then of course also token verification on any other API call. Thoughts?

Comment: SO is unfortunately not a "thoughts" platform. But rather a code debugging place.

Comment: "Empowering the world to develop technology through collective knowledge" -StackOverflow. It's a platform for learning from others. A platform for helping each other.

Comment: Yeah, there are several ways to help and to ask questions tho: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: "inspire answers that explain 'why' and _**'how'**_". If you can't help me, that's okay. But this right here is only taking up both of our time. I'm only looking to a solution as to _**how**_ I should do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @kissu Stack Overflow is for far more than just code debugging.  In fact, the most helpful questions [generally aren't debugging questions, but rather ask how to do something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364585/165261).